# How can I run a for loop that subsets multiple lists all of which contain dataframes

Tags: r

I have 5 lists called "nightclub", "hospital", "bar", "attraction", "social_facility" all of which contain a data frame called osm_points. I want to create a new list with 5 dataframes with the names of the original dataframes that only contain 3 vectors "osm_id","name","addr.postcode" with no NA values for the vector "addr.postcode". Below is my attempted code, I do not know another way to subset lists without $ (which gives me an error for having an atomic vector), or without the square brackets. Let know if you guys have some advice.

```
vectors <- c("osm_id","name","addr.postcode")
features <- c("nightclub", "hospital", "bar", "attraction", "social_facility")
datasets <- list()
n <- 0


for (i in features){
  n <- n + 1
  datasets[[n]] <- paste(i)[["osm_points"]][!is.na(paste(i)[["osm_points"]][["addr.postcode"]]), variables]
}
```

I managed to do this operation without a for loop (below), but I want to be able to code better and do it all in one operation. Thanks so much for your help.

```
nightclub1 <- nightclub$osm_points[!is.na(nightclub$osm_points$addr.postcode), variables]
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code using `lapply` :

```
result <- lapply(mget(features), function(x) 
                 x$osm_points[!is.na(x$osm_points$addr.postcode), vectors])
```

`result` should have list of 5 dataframe one for each `features` with only `vectors` column and without `NA` value for `addr.postcode`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your lists into a list to have something to iterate over.

As you have it, `features` is a character vector. In your first iteration `i` is `"nightclub"`, a string. `paste(i)` changes nothing, it is still `"nightclub"`. So your code becomes `"nightclub"[["osm_points"]]...`, but you need `nightclub[["osm_points"]]`.

```
## make a list of lists
list_of_lists <- mget(features)

## then you can do 
for(i in seq_along(list_of_lists)) {
  datasets[[i]] <- list_of_lists[[i]][["osm_points"]]...
}
```

Substituting `list_of_lists[[i]]` wherever you currently have `paste(i)`.

Comment: Great thanks pal, just tried it an works perfectly!